# Image registration algorithms / techniques used to enable extraction of fields from scanned document?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]
I am trying to determine the best method to extract handwritten data from a scanned document.

The handwritten data is in specific boxed areas. I generated the digital version of the document, and therefore I know both the co-ordinates of the boxed areas, and could also  generate additional variations of the document if need be (i.e. a version that is masked to make the fields easier to extract)

The reason I can't just extract the fields using the co-ordinates from document generation is there is shifting/scaling/perspective modifications which are occurring during the scanning process, which can push/pull the co-ordinates for each individual box differently (the scanned document does have corner markers used for alignment, but even so unintended transformations commonly take place).

I assume high level there are two ways to address this issue: step through the co-ordinates of each box on the page and attempt to "correct" them with some technique/algorithm, or compare a completed form with a blank form (masked?) and try to extract the correct fields that way.

What is the most efficient technique / algorithm to adjust for these modifications and accurately extract the areas which contain handwriting? Are there other options?

Comment: If your box is surrounded by lines, you can easily find it by correlation or by any other method (hough transform etc.). BTW, if image could be rotated, correlation will give you bad results, but Hough transforms will help you to determine angle of rotation (because main lines in documents are horizontals and verticals). After rotation correction you can really do a simple correlation with etalon to find offset coordinates.

Comment: Without seeing the form, I'd just be guessing. My last project identified patterns of dots. What's handy about dots, is a dot is a dot no matter what rotation it sits. The patterns of dots can form landmarks, which the software can use as rotational origin point. By knowing an origin point and angle, it is easy to extract regions. The pattern of dots can also indicate resolution. I'm confused why corner marks can only get to within 5 degrees. Marks spaced that far apart should do much better than that.

Comment: Posting some images of your forms will help finding some solution.

Comment: I have added an form image as suggested to help explain the problem better. I should also clarify that during the preprocessing stage the image is rotated based on corner markers to be oriented correctly - the issue I am experiencing is related to warping happening within only certain portions of the captured image.

Comment: The original image has white boxes, which are somehow being scanned as gray. If you could get the boxes to scan white, you could look for the white background to identify the box. Even if gray, as long as the gray is distinguishable from the tinted background, you could use that for location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - In this scenario I don't control the capture process - meaning in some cases the background of the captured document may appear as white, while in others it may appear as gray, depending on the capture device settings - hence the ideal solution would function in either scenario.

Comment: Even as gray, the boxes are lighter than the background. If you take a rolling average (single pixels can do weird things) of the pixel darkeness, you should see a major change when the darkness changes between the background and the box. By looking for a 10% change in darkness, it wouldn't matter if the box were gray or white, it just has to be noticeably lighter.

Comment: @HipHop-opatamus first of all be sure there is no "best method". But, using SURF with a decent key point matcher gives perfect results for your example and then the image registration gives perfect results too. Have you tried anything based on key point detection and matching ?

Comment: @ALL could you advice some python libraries for such kind of image recognition/proccesing?

Answer (score 0):

There many possible [techniques](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885603001379) that can achieve nearly 100% accuracy for your problem.

Just follow steps described on this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24809/Image-Alignment-Algorithms. In short, you first compute optical flow between two images and then estimate transformation that produces such optical flow.

Note: this approach works best when matched images are almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach would do. Some more details: since you have printed letters in the form such as "Section A", "A6" and "other", and you mentioned you have corner markers for alignment, you could use them as landmarks,  perform a `template matching` to find the coordinates of the landmarks in original and scanned documents. Then use these two sets of landmarks (The corner marks might be sufficient) to generate an affine transformation `M = cv2.getAffineTransform(landmarks1, landmarks2)`, apply `cv2.warpAffine(img, M, ...)` to the scanned image, to transform it to match the original document. With this, the boxes will be aligned properly (might still have a little bit of shift), then you could locate each boxes correctly. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-affine-transformation/

After typing all the above I found this webpage talking about the same thing with code: https://learnopencv.com/feature-based-image-alignment-using-opencv-c-python/